# Use @Field and @Body parameters in Retrofit together

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit to POST some data to my back-end. I need to send 3 Strings and one custom Place object. Here is what I am doing:

```
@POST("/post/addphoto/")
    public void addImage(@Field("image_url") String url, @Field("caption") String caption, @Field("google_place_id") String placeId, @Body Place place, Callback<UploadCallBack> response);
```

With this, I am getting this error:

```
@Field parameters can only be used with form encoding.
```

And when I use `@FormUrlEncoded`, like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/post/addphoto/")
        public void addImage(@Field("image_url") String url, @Field("caption") String caption, @Field("google_place_id") String placeId, @Body Place place, Callback<UploadCallBack> response);
```

I get this error:

```
@FormUrlEncoded or @Multipart can not be used with @Body parameter.
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Tiwari, may I know if you want image_url to be appended to /post/addphoto url?

Comment: @cgr No, I don't want to append it. Actually, image_url is the url of an image from facebook which I want to store in back-end along with some other fields. The Place object is what I get for location that is associated with that image, extracted from facebook.

Comment: as far as i know, you need to look at the situation as if you have only 1 place to hold the data in the request, it will be either RAW (body) or Form-shaped (FormUrlEncoded+Part) so here it's like you are trying to mix 2 data-structures in one place , this can't be done

Comment: what data format your backend expects ? FormUrlEnceode should be used only for form type. Your backend expects form data ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, made it work. @Body and @Field can not be used together. If @Body is being used, it should be the only parameter and it can not be combined with @FormUrlEncode or @MultiPart. So dropped that idea. Another option was to use only @Field and send the Place object as a JSON string.

Here is what I did for API interface:

```
@POST("/post/addphoto/")
    public void addImage(@Field("image_url") String url, @Field("caption") String caption, @Field("google_place_id") String placeId, @Field("facebook_place") String place, Callback<UploadCallBack> response);
```

And this is how I created the value to be sent for `facebook_place` field:

```
Place place = ...
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
String placeJSON = gson.toJson(place);
```