# Retrofit 2 - Post FieldMap with Body Object

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to post a HashMap and a Object using Retrofit.
I tried this code below but received `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
@POST("update")
Call<RSP010> postApi010(@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> defaultData, @Body User user);
```

Logcat

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @FieldMap parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1)
```

But when I add `@FormUrlEncoded`. It said

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #2)
```

**UPDATE CODE**

```
public static HashMap<String, String> defaultData(){
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("last_get_time", String.valueOf(SharedPreferencesHelper.getLongValue(AppConstants.LAST_GET_UPDATE)));
    map.put("duid", SharedPreferencesHelper.getStringValue(AppConstants.DUID));
    return map;
```

My Object which I want to post

```
int profile_id;
private String name;
private String name_kana; // あいうえお
private int gender; // 1 nam 2 nu
private String birth_day;
private String birth_time;
private String birth_place;
private String relationship;
```

Explain:

I want to post multiple variables via API to server. FieldMap `defaultData` for default variables I want to use in every API.

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body I've read this, it said instead of posting all separate variables of an object, I can post an object directly.

Comment: can you explain problem with data and api signature?

Comment: @PratikPopat I updated code and explain.

Comment: here you go, check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34392376/3800164)

Comment: are duid and last_get_time query params or headers?

Comment: @PratikPopat in query params sir

Answer (score 7):

You can send `@Body User user` with `@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> defaultData` like

```
    String user = new Gson().toJson(user);
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("last_get_time", String.valueOf(SharedPreferencesHelper.getLongValue(AppConstants.LAST_GET_UPDATE)));
    map.put("duid", SharedPreferencesHelper.getStringValue(AppConstants.DUID));
    map.put("duid", SharedPreferencesHelper.getStringValue(AppConstants.DUID));
    map.put("user", user);
```

**OR**

Use `@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody>`

```
@Multipart
@POST("update")
Call<RSP010> postApi010(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> defaultData);
```

And create your request parameters

```
Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("last_get_time", toRequestBody(String.valueOf(SharedPreferencesHelper.getLongValue(AppConstants.LAST_GET_UPDATE))));
map.put("duid", toRequestBody(SharedPreferencesHelper.getStringValue(AppConstants.DUID)));
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"),new Gson().toJson(user));
map.put("user", body);

// This method  converts String to RequestBody
public static RequestBody toRequestBody (String value) {
     RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value);
     return body ;
}
```

Comment: Your answer will not work. Because `user` is a Object, not a `String`

Comment: You can convert it into `String` using `Gson` and can send it as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your method to:

```
@POST("update")
Call<RSP010> postApi010(@Query("last_get_time") String lastGetTime,
                        @Query("duid") String uid,
                        @Body User user);
```

Comment: Can we migrate it instead of not using my `defaultData`?

Comment: you can call like 
getYourService().postApi010("your_get_time", "uid", user);